# Conflict between ruby version in gemfile and local ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm having trouble running running an app because of its ruby version. But from everything I can tell, I have the right version of ruby running. What am I doing wrong?

```html
user@computer project % rails s
Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.1
user@computer project % rbenv local
2.7.1
user@computer project % ruby -v
ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-darwin19]
user@computer project % which ruby
/Users/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

(I've also tried switching the ruby version in the gemfile from `2.7.1` to `2.6.3`, but when I do, it gives me the opposite message (that I have `2.6.3` specified but I'm running `2.7.1`).

**Update:** Turns out this problem is specific to running in zsh. Using bash works fine.

Comment: When rbenv doesn't work right remove it and all installed Rubies and then start from scratch. Don't even bother troubleshooting.

Comment: it seems, rails is using system ruby (2.6.3 at this moment for MacOS). check which rails you are using e.g. `type rails` `which rails`. If in doubt run with, `bundle exec rails` or `bin/rails s`. I think your rails installation and command line is messed up, not the rbenv.

Answer (score 1):

`rails` invokes the global binary. You can try:

- `bundle exec rails` instead, or
- `gem install rails` in your Ruby 2.7.1 environment.